# Can this Int32 initializer ever return nil?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Objective C:

```
NSInteger x = // some value...
NSString* str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)x];

// str is passed to swift
```

Swift:

```
let string:String = str!
let x = Int32(string)! // crash!
```

Sorry for the disjointed code, this is from a crash reported in a large existing codebase. I don't see how it's possible for the int->string->int32 conversion to fail. NSInteger can be too big for int32, but I would expect the explicit `(int)` to prevent that case (it will give the wrong value, but still shouldn't crash).

I have been unable to reproduce this, so I'm trying to figure out if my understanding is completely wrong.

**Edit:** obviously it is theoretically possible for it to return `nil` in the sense that the spec says so. I'm asking if/how it can in *this specific situation*.

Comment: Could it be that a different string than the one from the Objective-C side ends up being consumed in Swift?

Comment: It seems to me that this cannot really happen. I would advise to start looking for other reasons. Maybe the string is empty for some reason?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using `Int32`, the initializer can return `nil` if the value supplied to it is out of the range `Int32` can take. In your specific case this can easily happen, since as the [documentation of NSInteger](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsinteger) states, it can take 64bit values in 64bit applications (which is the only supported configuration since iOS11).

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/int32/2927184-init) of `Int32.init(_:String)` clearly states that the cases when the failable initializer can fail:

> If description is in an invalid format, or if the value it denotes in
>   base 10 is not representable, the result is nil. For example, the
>   following conversions result in nil:

```
Int(" 100")                       // Includes whitespace
Int("21-50")                      // Invalid format
Int("ff6600")                     // Characters out of bounds 
Int("10000000000000000000000000") // Out of range
```

Comment: But look at how the string is being created in objective c. How could that string be in an invalid format?

Comment: @Max I haven't talked about an invalid format at all. The issue is that in Obj-C you use an `NSInteger`, whose value is 64bits when building 64bit applications, so converting an `NSInteger` to an `Int32` can clearly fail (I assumed you are building a 64bit app, since iOS11 only supports those).

Comment: Does casting an `NSInteger` to `int` not truncate it to 32 bits?